# Best way to check for nil and update hash value

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a hash  where the values are all arrays. I want to look up a key in this hash. If it exists I want to add a value to the array. If it does not exist (hash[key] returns nil) then I need to create the array and and add one value. Currently I have this:

```
hash[key].push elem unless hash[key].nul?
hash[key] ||= [elem]
```

This involves 3 lookups. I'm new to ruby so I'm sure there's a better way to do this. What is it?

My original plan was to make the default value for the hash [ ]. Then I can just use:

```
hash[key].push elem
```

Unfortunately if the key does not exist, that will only change the default value and not add a new key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
(hash[key] ||= []) << elem
```

However Arup's answer is much better.

Comment: BS (you don't mind the nickname, I presume), I am responding to a fleeting comment you made, comparing your approach with @Arup's.  Yours is the traditional approach.  I did a benchmark of the two in one context and `||= ..` was significantly faster. I personally prefer this for how it reads, because the creation of the hash is sometimes far removed from where the action is.  On the other hand, you can use Arup's in situations where the hash may have `nil` values.  I think it's a toss-up.  btw, if you had given Arup's answer, I expect he would have given yours.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree with you. I am always fan of the syntax this answer used. No doubt I like this. But whenever I find Ruby API has something, which I want, I directly go for it.

Answer (score 5):

In this case you need to create a hash as below :

```
hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

The above is created to handle situations like your. Look [`new {|hash, key| block } → new_hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-new)

```
hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }

hash[:key1] << 1
hash[:key2] << 2
hash[:key1] << 3

hash # => {:key1=>[1, 3], :key2=>[2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your hash with a default value.

```
hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
hash[key].push elem
```